# datagridvie refresh on save update or delete actions

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am working with datagrid in c#,i want that when i save,update or delete the database with the form the grid will should be refresh (updated) on these actions what should i do to achive this
please help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by

Rebinding the datasource to the DataGridView